# Header for DrawerNavigation with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation-drawer, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm on ReactNative and i'm using native-base and react-navigation npm.

I got this and my question is how I can have a header, up to the button "Home", I looked into the documentation of react-navigation but it's not really cleared.

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/docs/api/navigators/DrawerNavigator.md

[image]

**Like this (the image is fix, it's just to put a logo here)**

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can implement custom content component for drawer. There you can also simply render navigation items using `DrawerItems`. For example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { DrawerItems, DrawerNavigation } from 'react-navigation'

const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#f50057',
        height: 140,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>
        Header
      </Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
  </View>
)

const Navigation = DrawerNavigator({
  // ... your screens
}, {
  // define customComponent here
  contentComponent: DrawerContent,
})
```

Comment: is this still valid with the new version of React-Navigation ?

Answer (score 4):

For Drawer Navigation, you Can add Your own Header & Footer and Make Your Own Styles with `contentComponent` Config:
First `import { DrawerItems, DrawerNavigation } from 'react-navigation'` Then

**Header Before `DrawerItems`:**

`contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><Text>Your Own Header Area Before</Text><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>` .

[image: Header Before DrawerItems]

**Footer After `DrawerItems`:**

`contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /><Text>Your Own Footer Area After</Text></ScrollView>` .

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using ***contentComponent*** option in drawer nav config. Two ways you could do it based on the level of configuration required:

**Method 1.**

**DrawerItems** from react-navigation(handles navigation on its own) -

```
import {DrawerItems, DrawerNavigation} from 'react-navigation';
export default DrawerNavigator({
// ... your screens
}, {
// define customComponent here
contentComponent: (props) =>
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
<Text>Header</Text>
<ScrollView>
<DrawerItems {...props} />
</ScrollView>
</View>
});
```

This creates a fixed header with scroll view for the menu items below it.

**Method 2.**

**Creating your own custom component** -

```
import { DrawerNavigation } from 'react-navigation'
export default DrawerNavigator({
// ... your screens
}, {
// define customComponent here
contentComponent: props => <SideMenu {...props}>
});
```

Here SideMenu is your own component to display in the drawer. You can use react-navigation **NavigationActions.navigate(screen)** to handle routing on onPress of menu items.

For more detailed explanation on the second method https://medium.com/@kakul.gupta009/custom-drawer-using-react-navigation-80abbab489f7

Answer (score 2):

nested navigator should be like this:

```
const Router = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
    Test: {screen: TestScreen}
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#2980b9'},
        headerTintColor: '#fff'
    }
});

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    App: {screen: Router}
});
```

for ui:

1) https://github.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-react-navigation-stack-navigator/blob/master/src/SideBar/SideBar.js

2) https://github.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-react-navigation-stack-navigator/blob/master/src/HomeScreen/index.js